# Adding a date field to a XML file in C#

Tags: c#, xml, date

I am after a C# code. I am planing to create a C# form with just 2 things in it.

1. Date picker field(where I can select a date from a drop down list.
2. A button which will save the above date I selected to a XML file.

Can someone let me know how to code it or share me a C# code for it. The XML file is a file for creating Schedule Task and the date format it uses is 2017-08-24T11:15:13

Example of my XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.3" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
<RegistrationInfo>
<Author>CLRC\xub61645</Author>
</RegistrationInfo>
<Triggers>
<TimeTrigger>
<StartBoundary>2017-08-24T11:15:13</StartBoundary>
<Enabled>true</Enabled>
</TimeTrigger>
</Triggers>
</Task>
```

Thanks in advance.
Eric

Comment: .NET documentation contains entire sections on XML serialization. Start there, eg with [Introducint XML Serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/introducing-xml-serialization). Besides, you did *not* explain what you want. Do you want to write an entire set of objects at once? Or are you trying to write out millions of objects, in which case you need to write one tag at a time?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is bluntly asking for code.

Comment: "Can someone let me know how to code it or share me a C# code for it." - No offense, Eric but that's not how SO works. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. We are glad to help if you have problems achieving your task.

Comment: Another option is to use LINQ to XML to [generate a tree of elements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/functional-construction-linq-to-xml) and serialize them. It's NOT easier than serialization though. In general, it's easier to create an instance of a Task class and serialize it

Comment: @Fildor one can safely assume that the OP doesn't know enough about XML to realize that this is a bad question. This isn't even a `give me the code` question - what code? To do what? To serialize a full graph, write individual elements?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I agree. But still - it *is* a bad question. I am trying to motivate OP to improve it. I hope that's coming across.

Comment: Eric, looking at the schema URL, I suspect that your question has nothing to do with adding an XML element. Your *real* question is how to register tasjs in Windows Scheduler or generate the task's XML definition. There *are* wrappers for this, eg [this one](https://github.com/dahall/taskscheduler). If you want to create your own XML, use [the schema](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383609(v=vs.85).aspx) and the `xsd` tool to create the classes, instantiate them, set the correct properties and then serialize them into XML

Comment: I am new to this and i am sorry if I have not asked it correctly. I just wanted to create a exe file which will ask me for date and then save it to a XML file. I have never done any programming but I did search the site for any help but i could not find anything where it will guide me to do what I want.

Comment: Hi All. I managed to get it to work thanks for the support.